# Map real numbers into [0:255] using fixed limits interval

Tags: functions

I got an interval from x0 to x1. I want all numbers inside this interval to be mapped (preferably linear) from 0 to 255. All numbers below x0 should be mapped to 0. All numbers above x1 should be mapped to 255.

I can accept that the mapping in between is not perfectly linear, as that would (afaik) not be possible). However it is crucial that the mapped numbers do not exceed the [0:255] interval.

Curently my best bet is:

$$
x_{mapped}=\frac{x}{(x_1-x_0)+x}\cdot255
$$

Anyone got a suggestion on how to do better than this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function does exactly what you want :
$$f(x)= \max( 0, \min (255, 255\times \frac{x-x_0}{x_1-x_0})) $$

Comment: That could do, I just have to figure out how to code it in VB, but that should be very doable.

Answer (score 0):

You want a linear function going through points $x_0, 0$ to $x_1, 255$ (so $f(x_0) = 0$ and $f(x_1)=255$.

The function through $(x_0, y_0)$ and $(x_1, y_1)$ is described by the equation

$$x-x_0= \frac{x_1 - x_0}{y_1 - y_0}(y-y_0)$$

In your case, $y_0=0, y_1=255$, so the equation is

$$x-x_0 = \frac{x_1-x_0}{255}\cdot y$$

or, if we isolate $y$:

$$u=255\cdot \frac{x-x_0}{x_1-x_0}.$$

Notice that it is a perfectly linear function, so your sentence

> I can accept that the mapping in between is not perfectly linear, as that would (afaik) not be possible

is **False**.

Just out of curiosity, what made you think it would not be possible in the first place?

Comment: As I imagine it, since the function output is not allowed to exeed 255 or be less than 0, the function needs to be perfectly flat outside this region. In my head, that lead to a non-linear function, as this would cause the function to "break" in the points 0 and 255. But I might be wrong.

Comment: @Noceo Oh, yes, outside $[x_0, x_1]$, you set the function to be $0$ and $255$, so it's not linear. But on $[x_0, x_1]$, it's linear.

Comment: My initial idea was that it would be easier with a function with a single derivative in each point (whats the english word for this?), rather than three different functions for different input regions. After reading your answers though, it is proably simpler to do it in another way. Thanks for you inputs.

Comment: @Noceo You can always approximate your function with a smooth function, but I think that would just complicate things...